# Setup event-listeners more quickly (typescript)

Tags: typescript

Very simple question: I have a codebase, which contains functions for each possible event that could be fired from `Client.on()`:

```js
Client.on('connect', onConnect);
Client.on('message', onMessage);
Client.on('ping', onPing);
//...
```

All of the valid event stings are declared in the `Client.on` declaration, ie.

```js
class Client{
  public on(event: 'connect'|'message'|'ping', listener: (info: dataInfoContainer) => void): this;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe something like:

```js
Client.on.arguments[0].types.forEach((type) => eval(`Client.on(${type}, on${type.toTileCase}`));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put all your functions like `onConnect` into an *object* indexed by event name:

```
const listeners = {
  connect(info: dataInfoContainer) {
    // ...
  },
  message(info: dataInfoContainer) {
  }
  // ...
};
for (const [eventName, listener] of Object.entries(listeners)) {
  Client.on(eventName as keyof typeof listeners, listener);
}
```